# Get the First Column in the same row

Tags: vba, excel, find, row

How can I find the first column same row in a Excel-sheet with vba?

I wrote a macro for finding a word in a cell an I need to get an message into the same row first column.

Best regards

Answer (score 3):

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(aCell.Row,1)
```

Where `aCell` is the range which has the word which your searched

Alternatively, you can also use this

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & aCell.Row)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
aCell.Offset(0, -aCell.Column + 1).Value = "This is my message."
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the need to know the sheet name, use

```
aCell.EntireRow.Cells(1,1)
```